# Angular js trigger routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a reset link, which is meant to reset my angular js app...

```
<a ng-click="resetApp()">reset</a>
```

I am handling the button press in the main controller...

```
$scope.resetApp = function(){

    if(confirm("You will lose data...")){

      $scope.user.reset();

      // not sure how to do this in more angular js way
      window.location = "/#";

    }

}
```

I am not sure if setting the `window.location` as I have done is the right way to do things. It works for me, but does not seem like the correct way, and I have not been able to find out ow to do it online.

Comment: +1...I was just thinking about this earlier...I have a few `window.location = '/'` in my app, seems ugly though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been using the so-called AngularJS way like this, at least the routing is handled by AngularJS rather than browser directly.

```
function Ctrl($scope, $location) {

    $scope.resetApp = function(){

        ...

        $location.url('/');
    }
}
```

The path is what is defined in the `Route Provider` like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        }).
...
```

Comment: Could you give a little more context, or a pointer to where to find out more about that. I have a reference to `$location` but am not able to set the current page that way. It builds a nice url for me if I inspect `$location` afterwards, with the protocol and server name etc... but not changing the page.

Comment: It uses the path defined in the routeProvider.

Comment: In case you want to add path to your existing url, use $location.path('/path_name'); Your url will look like this: 'www.your_url/#/path_name'